# Erro compileDebugKotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, build, kotlin

Erro:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
>   Compilation error. See log for more details

Build.gradle Modulo App

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
    //    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "xx.xxx.xxx..xxxx"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 3
            versionName "1.0.2"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
        }
        /* Remove This to remove Crashlytics and Fabric */
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
            transitive = false
        }
    /*    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }*/
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
        compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Esse erro é muito genérico, você poderia editar a resposta, adicionando o output do `gradle console`?

Comment: Vá no gradle console, lá ele vai lhe dar uma referencia para o problema e edite sua pergunta